# Need to read the data from iHealth Blood Pressure Monitor (KN-550BT)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, business-process-management

We are using the iHealth KN-550BT for development and trying to read the Blood Pressure data via Bluetooth.

We didn't find the standard 0x1810 Blood Pressure service and its 2A35 Blood pressure measurement characteristic from this device.  However, we found a custom service (636F6D2E-6A69-7561-6E2E-425041563231) and two characteristics inside (7265632E-6A69-7561-6E2E-425041563231 and 7365642E-6A69-7561-6E2E-425041563231).

What hex value should we send to the 7265632E-6A69-7561-6E2E-425041563231 characteristic to get the blood pressure data from the device? and what's the meaning of each bit of returned value from 7365642E-6A69-7561-6E2E-425041563231?

We tried to find the documentation from iHealth's website, but there was no luck. Hope someone here can answer our question. Your time and help are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like this information is available to the general public. I would just contact the manufacturer asking them for this information.

Comment: Yea, we sent an email and created a service ticket on the manufacturer's website. Hope they can answer them soon. Thanks!